# Custom routes with defineRoutes

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

Does someone have some extra info about defineRoutes function in remix.config?

I have a  this route:

```
{     
"id": "routes/__main/city/$city", "path": "/city/:city",
"file":"routes/__main/city/$city.tsx"
}
```

and in defineRoutes I made something like this:

```
routes: async (defineRoutes) => {
    return defineRoutes((route) => {
      route("/citta/:city", "routes/__main/city/$city.tsx"); 
    });
  },
```

I want that both /citta/test and /city/test will go on the same file located here `routes/__main/city/$city.tsx`.

But when I run the code only the /citta/test route is active the other one /city/test will throw error.

As I read from the docs here https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#routes, what I want to achive should be possible.

Have I misunderstood the use of defineRoutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved without the use of `defineRoutes`. Revert your `remix.config` changes and let Remix handle the routing for you by placing your routes within `app/routes`.

Move `routes/__main/city/$city.tsx` in your `app` directory and add an additional folder structure `app/routes/__main/citta/$city.tsx`. So you have two folders `/city` and `/citta` next to each other. They will share all the nested routing that you introduced with `__main`.

Export the following from your `app/routes/__main/citta/$city.tsx` file:

```js
import CityComponent from '~/routes/__main/city/$city';

// re-export loader, action, and all other functionality
export * from '~/routes/__main/city/$city'
// re-use the default export from your other route
export default CityComponent;
```

This lets you reuse the code from your `city/$city.tsx` file in `citta/$city.tsx`.

**Note:** Make sure to name both files in `citta/` and `city/` `$city.tsx` to avoid naming discrepancies. Otherwise your re-exported loader and action won't work as the parameter name differs.

Comment: Thanks, this is a solution that I've made aswell and actually working. There is only one negative aspect of this, you have to increase your codebase with folder and files that basically do the same things. But hey it's working :)

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer or mark as answered so that other people can profit from it, too!

Comment: And you are right, additional folders and files but it also keeps all your routes in one place (`routes/`) and it's explicit about it!

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried to colocate all my code in modules and re-export the page  components from `app/routes` like this:

```
import LoginPage,  from "~/modules/auth/LoginPage";
export * from "~/modules/auth/LoginPage";
export default LoginPage;
```

but I ran into React 18 hydration issues. The working solution for me was re-exporting this way:

```
import LoginPage, { action, loader } from "~/modules/auth/LoginPage";

export { action, loader };
export default LoginPage;
```